# c# Static or Non Static Class

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, static, non-static

I have a c# windows forms mp3 player application. I have the audio files in my Resources folder and a separate "MyAudio" static class which handles all the audio related work like playing and increasing volume etc.
From my Form, I just call the play method using:

```
 MyAudio.Play(track);
```

In the MyAudio class, I have a WindowsMediaPlayer object declared as:

```
 private static WindowsMediaPlayer obj=new WindowsMediaPlayer();
```

My Question is, in terms of efficiency and less memory usage, is it better to declare MyAudio class as static or non static? Is it wise to create a Object of the MyAudio class in form and then call the methods or directly call using class Name?
Also is it good practice to declare the instance variables as static?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Keep in mind when using `static` classes, the object will live for the entire lifetime of your application. If you allocate a large resource inside, it will live throughout. Moreso, `static` classes tend to be less testable.

Comment: So for less memory usage, I should define them as non static and just create object everytime?

Comment: That is the approach i'd take for this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is indeed broad, but there are few design principles that you can take care of, while you are designing a class:

- Do I need the object and it's state throughout the application lifetime
- Do I need to maintain the state of class variables for future use
- Do I need to multi-thread or parallelize the application at any point of time
- Do I need to decouple the component in the future and used in other scenarios like Ajax based web scenario

Important thing in this case is that you are keen to maintain the state for the application lifetime and the amount of memory usage is fine for the application environment, since after initializing you would be able to get all the data from memory and don't need to query a source like database. However, this is good for the scenario where you need to initialize once and read as a static information in the rest of the application. In case you plan to re query the information, then the part purpose of using static type would be lost

Let's assume in the future you need to parallelize your code for performance enhancement, then static will come to haunt you, since it would be shared among threads and invariably would need a synchronization construct like lock, mutex, which will serialize all threads and thus purpose would be lost. Same things would happen in a Web / Ajax scenario  and your static component cannot handle the multiple parallel requests and will get corrupted until and unless synchronized. Here instance variable per thread is a boon, as they do task / data parallelization without requiring a lock, mutex

In my understanding static is a convenience, which many programmers misuse, by avoiding the instance variable and using at will, without understanding the implications. From the GC perspective, it cannot collect the static variable, so the working set of the application would invariably increase till it stabilize and will not decrease until and unless explicitly released by program, which is not good for any application, until and unless we are storing data to avoid network database calls.

Ideal design would suggest to always use the instance class, which gets created, does its work and gets released, not linger around. In case there's information that needs to be passed from one function to another like in your case from Play to Pause to Stop, then that data can be persisted to a static variable and modified in a thread safe manner, which is a much better approach

If we just take example given by you since it's a windows form, which does operations like Play, then static would be fine, as it is an executable running on a system, but for testing imagine a scenario that you initiate multiple instances by double clicking and play around on each one, by pressing different operations, then they all will access same static object and you may get a corruption issue, in fact to resolve such scenario you may even chose your class to be singleton, where at a given moment no more than one instance can exist in the memory, like it happens for Yahoo messenger, no matter how many times you click, always same instance comes up.

Answer (score 0):

There are no static instance variables. However its best practice to define static members if they don't have anything to do with a particular instance of the class.

Comment: Okay. So since my WindowsMediaPlayer object is just used inside the MyAudio class, I'll Declare it non static.

Comment: The question is always how many instances do you need... i guess you need one... make that static

Comment: And a static method can not reach instance fields ... at least not directly